# Alignment of the PDF title

Tags: pdf, title

Is there any possibility to centre the PDF title when the file is viewed on, say, AR? By default the title is left aligned.

Comment: What is "AR", please?

Comment: @slhck Adobe Reader, I'd assume. Not sure if they mean the window title bar or the title in the actual PDF itself, though.

Comment: Adobe Reader (AR) Sorry I missed it.  When I open a PDF file, it shows the name of the file followed by the title of the file for examples 'abc.pdf -- The tile of my PDF', which is left aligned.  I would like to have 'abc.pdf' on the left as it appears in the window title bar, and centre 'The title of my PDF'.  Not sure if it is possible at all taken into account that there is a variety of PDF readers.

Comment: @Reza: If you mean the window title: That depends on the OS, the window manager and the application.

Comment: @MartinSchröder You should post that as an answer so Reza can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "center the PDF title in the window title": That depends on the OS, the window manager and the application.